# Most Performant way to implement time-dependent status

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Central to a project I'm working on is a highlighting-mechanic that can be applied to certain items on the website. The idea is, that this highlighted-status is only active for a certain amount of time.

I'm trying to find the most performant way to achieve this (in querying, setting status, checking status and revoking it)

**A first approach** would be to set simply set a value 'highlighted:true' to the item. This seems to be the most performant way to query for highlighted items. The Drawback I see here, is that there also needs to be stored a date for the highlighting-action, but furthermore there needs to run an interval to check on the highlighted items and potentially revoke their highlighted status. Also the exact moment when the item stops beeing highlighted can't be determined exactly, since its depending on the interval of the check-function.

**A second approach** would be to mainly store the date of the highlighting-action and run the query against it. It seems that the query of highlighted objects is way less performant, since every item ever is beeing checked, and on top its not just a boolean, but a proper function that throws those differnt date-values around to check if it is still valid. On the upside there is no external cleanup-function neccessary and every highlighting period ends perfectly on time.

Would love to have your input on this. Is there maybe a clever pattern on this?

Comment: "It seems that the query of highlighted objects is way less performant" - it _seems_ or you actually measured that? With or without indexes?

Comment: @sergio Thats just my feeling for the described reasons, havent tested anything. Whats your opinion?

Comment: My opinion is that any performance-related decisions must be made with hard numbers in hands.